# How to remove coordinate axes in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I created this tikzpicture in geogebra.
I just want the vector instead of coordinate axes shown in picture after running. I do not how to set the code given so that axes are removed and get just the $\overrightarrow{OP}$ shown below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=4.8,
xmax=8.9,
ymin=3.0,
ymax=5.0,
xtick={5.0,6.0,...,8.0},
ytick={3.0,4.0,...,5.0},]
\clip(4.8,3.) rectangle (8.9,5.);
\draw [->,line width=2.pt] (4.99090909090911,3.607272727272724) -- (8.445454545454574,4.807272727272722);
\draw (4.9181818181818375,3.7709090909090874) node[anchor=north west] {$\text{O}$};
\draw (8.245454545454573,4.934545454545449) node[anchor=north west] {$\text P$};
\draw (6.354545454545478,4.898181818181813) node[anchor=north west] {$\overrightarrow{OP}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just remove the `axis` environment

Comment: or set `axis lines=none,`  (but as @DG' wrote, the axis environment looks unneeded here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @DG, remove the `axis` environment

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

\draw [->,line width=2.pt] 
     (5,3.6)node[below]{$O$} 
     --node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{OP}$} 
     (8.4,4.8)node[below]{$P$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```